# How to find Memory used percentage by postgres DB using postgres-exporter

Tags: postgresql, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-postgres-exporter

I am running postgres, postgres-exporter, prometheus, grafana and cadvisor all as docker containers.
I need to find the percentage of memory used by postgres.
My requirement is to send an alert when when postgres used more than 85% of memory.

I used below query, but I am not sure this gives exact memory usage.

```
sum(process_resident_memory_bytes) / sum(machine_memory_bytes) \* 100
```

Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Amila Senadheera - I am not able to understand the difference, can you explain your changes in my query

Comment: I didn't change your query, I add your code inside a code block to look better